# What's an adjective that describes Ophelia or someone who gives in to fate?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

In the Shakespearean play, Hamlet, Ophelia is found drowned in a body of water. I believe she saw all of her opportunities in front of her but as the people around her (i.e. Polonius, Claudius, Hamlet) made choices she saw each outcome of her life disappear until her only fate was to take her own life.

Comment: How about 'fatalistic'?

Comment: Quitter, Surrendered, Fatalist, Hopeless, Resigned, Given up, Abandoned..

Answer (score 2):

[**Resigned**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/resigned) comes to mind:

> Having accepted something unpleasant that one cannot do anything about.

[Long-suffering](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/long-suffering) might work too.

Answer (score 0):

I would propose "despondent"

de·spond·ent
dəˈspändənt/
adjective
in low spirits from loss of hope or courage.
synonyms:   disheartened, discouraged, dispirited, downhearted, downcast, crestfallen, down, low, disconsolate, despairing, wretched...

From Google